# titanium code interpreted at runtime, xamarin code compiled before runtime?

Tags: xamarin, titanium

Can you tell me if I understood the following difference between Appcelerator Titanium and Xamarin correctly?

Titaniums javascript code will be interpreted at runtime. In contrast, Xamarins C# code will be compiled to native code before runtime - resulting in much better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Titanium is compiled to native code. You can view the Xcode (Objective C) resulting project in the build/ folder.